# Dynamically generated MXML data doesn't get rendered

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

So I have a requirement to display dynamically generated data in the view.

For this, my idea was to create a mxml file and then use it as an object. Fill the data in the ibject and then use addChild to display it. But even after adding all the data. The dynamically generated mxml file doesn't gets displayed.

Code

**BuyTogetherGrid.MXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Box xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="80" height="60" xmlns:image="org.commodity.detail.image.*">
<mx:HBox>
    <image:ImageBox id="buyTogetherImg"></image:ImageBox>
    <mx:VBox id="textInfo">
        <mx:Box id="commonNameBox">
            <mx:Label id="commonName">
            </mx:Label>
        </mx:Box>
        <mx:Box id="commonPriceBox">
            <mx:Label id="commonPrice">
            </mx:Label>
        </mx:Box>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:HBox>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function createGrid():void{
            this.buyTogetherImg = new ImageBox();
            this.commonName = new Label();
            this.commonPrice = new Label();
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:Box>
```

This is my MXMl File. My idea was to create an object of this mxml object. Add data to buyTogetherImg, CommonName, CommonPrice and then use addChild

**Part where I set the data**

```
<mx:HBox id="buyTogetherBox" width="100%" borderColor="black">

</mx:HBox>
```

The upper HBox is the container where I will keep all my generated object

```
var buyTogetherBox : BuyTogetherGrid = new BuyTogetherGrid();
buyTogetherBox.createGrid();

for each(var item:cmListItem in commod.items){
       if(item.dataFormat == 2){
           buyTogetherBox.buyTogetherImg.imgData = item.value as ImageData;
       } else if(item.dataFormat == 0){
          buyTogetherBox.commonName.text = item.value.toString();
       } else if(item.dataFormat == 3){
            buyTogetherBox.commonPrice.text = StringUtil.numToStrPrice(item.value as Number);
                    }
       }
       this.buyTogetherBox.addChild(buyTogetherBox);
}
```

The code check some conditions and add the data. However the buyTogetherBox is not visible. But if I try something like

```
this.buyTogetherBox.addChild(buyTogetherBox.buyTogetherImg);
```

then i can see the image in the H:Box.

I am pretty new to Flex. so may be I would have missed something

Comment: Is there something wrong with your MXML above? I see an opening `mx:Box` tag, but no closing one.

Comment: Oh sorry, that line disn't have the proper indentation so, SO just ignored it. Fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving the statically created instances of the label and image control unused and creating new instances instead. Basically, the entire `createGrid()` function is unnecessary. You already have the controls created in MXML. Just use them with creating new instances.

```
var grid:BuyTogetherGrid = new BuyTogetherGrid();
grid.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, this.grid_creationCompleteHandler);
```

Elsewhere in the same class...

```
private function grid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    // Set your properties here
}
```

Comment: I tried that already. But for some reason those controls were not initialized and just null. That used to throw throw error like cannot set property or call functions on null(something like that) . That's why i had to create it this way

Comment: In any case the new instances of label are still associated with "buyTogetherBox". If I use, this.buyTogetherBox.addChild(buyTogetherBox.buyTogetherImg); it does adds the image. I don't really know how mxml works, I am pretty new. So i may haven't considered some property of MXML

Comment: The image and label instances are not created immediately after the parent is instantiated. This is an oddity of the Flash platform. No way around it. The simplest way would be to wait for the `creationComplete` event to be fired from your component. I've added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

As Pranav said it takes some time to create MXML components and if you try to assess them immediately you will get a null pointer exception because they don't exist yet. A quick and dirty solution is to make public variables in your BuyTogetherGrid.MXML and then bind the text properties to these variables, like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Box xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="80" height="60" xmlns:image="org.commodity.detail.image.*">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

[Bindable] public var imageData:ImageData;
[Bindable] public var name:String;
[Bindable] public var price:String;

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:HBox>
    <image:ImageBox id="buyTogetherImg" imgData={imageData}/>
    <mx:VBox id="textInfo">
    <mx:Box id="commonNameBox">
        <mx:Label id="commonName" text="{name}">
        </mx:Label>
    </mx:Box>
    <mx:Box id="commonPriceBox">
        <mx:Label id="commonPrice" text="{price}">
        </mx:Label>
    </mx:Box>
</mx:VBox>
```

and then you do

```
buyTogetherBox.imageData = yourImageData;
buyTogetherBox.name = "Your Name";
buyTogetherBox.imageData = "Your price";
```

and yes, remove the unnecessary createGrid() method